# How can I make my Lua script do a natural curve down rather then juddering diagonally?

Tags: lua, mouseevent, mouse, logitech-gaming-software

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents  (true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
      repeat
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
          repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0,11)
            Sleep(15)
            MoveMouseRelative(-1,0)
          until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this code in lua however it makes it judder and need it to curve slowly down. What can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move smoothly you may try to jump with shorter steps and sleep for shorter periods.
This would require special versions for `Sleep` and `MoveMouseRelative`:

```
do
   local frac_x, frac_y = 0, 0
   local orig_MoveMouseRelative = MoveMouseRelative

   function MoveMouseRelative(x, y)
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x + x, frac_y + y
      x, y = math.floor(frac_x), math.floor(frac_y)
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x - x, frac_y - y
      while x ~= 0 or y ~= 0 do
         local dx = math.min(127, math.max(-127, x))
         local dy = math.min(127, math.max(-127, y))
         x, y = x - dx, y - dy
         orig_MoveMouseRelative(dx, dy)
      end
   end

   local function busyloop(final_ctr)
      final_ctr = final_ctr - final_ctr%1
      local ctr, prev_ms, ms0, ctr0 = 0
      while ctr ~= final_ctr do
         local ms = GetRunningTime()
         if prev_ms and ms ~= prev_ms then
            if not ms0 then
               ms0, ctr0 = ms, ctr
            elseif final_ctr < 0 and ms - ms0 > 500 then
               return (ctr - ctr0) / (ms - ms0)
            end
         end
         prev_ms = ms
         ctr = ctr + 1
      end
   end
   local coefficient = busyloop(-1)
   local orig_Sleep = Sleep

   function Sleep(ms)
      if ms > 30 then
         return orig_Sleep(ms)
      else
         return busyloop(ms * coefficient)
      end
   end

end


EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event,arg)
   if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
         repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
               repeat
                  MoveMouseRelative(-0.1, 1.1)
                  Sleep(1.5)  -- should be about 1ms for really smooth movement
               until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
      end
   end
end
```

---

**UPDATE**
If you don't have unused CPU core there is another version, not so smooth, but with a constant speed

```
do
   local frac_x, frac_y, prev_time = 0, 0

   function StartMoving()
      prev_time = GetRunningTime()
   end

   function MoveMouseForAWhile(x, y)
      Sleep(1)
      local time = GetRunningTime()
      time, prev_time = time - prev_time, time
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x + time * x, frac_y + time * y
      x, y = math.floor(frac_x), math.floor(frac_y)
      frac_x, frac_y = frac_x - x, frac_y - y
      while x ~= 0 or y ~= 0 do
         local dx = math.min(127, math.max(-127, x))
         local dy = math.min(127, math.max(-127, y))
         x, y = x - dx, y - dy
         MoveMouseRelative(dx, dy)
      end
   end

end


EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event,arg)
   if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
         repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
               local speed = 1.5
               StartMoving()
               repeat
                  MoveMouseForAWhile(-0.1 * speed, 1.1 * speed)
               until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: The OP gave this comment (in a now-deleted answer): _thanks for the help, it's definitely smoother, what should i do to make it move slower down and slower left? As i tried changing the move mouse relative values by decimals and it changes it by quite a lot_.

Comment: @armitageshanks99 - To modify speed, change horizontal `-0.1` and vertical `1.1` values in the line `MoveMouseRelative(-0.1, 1.1)`.  For example, try `MoveMouseRelative(-0.05, 0.55)` to move twice slower

Comment: is there any possible way to make even smaller increments to the MoveMouseRelative like smaller then 0.05 for example 0.005 thank you

Comment: @armitageshanks99 - Yes, you can use any speed value.  `0.005` is OK.

Comment: is there a way to change the x and y values without affecting each other as when I change the x value it affects the y value?thanks

Comment: `when I change the x value it affects the y value` - What do you mean?

Comment: so the MoveMouseRelative(0.1,1.1)has 2 co ordinates x and y when I change either of them it affects them both is there a way I can change 1 of them without affecting the other like when I decrease the x value it makes the y value decrease too and go down slower

Comment: In other words, you want to save the direction, but change the speed?  You can do it by multiplying both coordinates by speed value: `local speed=2 MoveMouseRelative(0.1*speed, 1.1*speed)`

Comment: thanks also I've been using the script and have noticed the speed changes randomly whilst using it and the mouse moves at slow speeds sometimes and fast speeds?

Comment: You CPU is overloaded.  For my method to work, you should have one free CPU core.  In other words, the game must use lesser CPU cores than you have available.

Comment: ?u think so that's the cause rly I have a ryzen 5 3600

Comment: so how could I fix it and make 1 free core

Comment: some games have an option (somewhere in settings file or a command line option) to occupy specified amount of cpu cores

Comment: Answer updated.  Please check new version of the script.  Is it better than the first version?

Comment: its deffinetly better thanks allot for your help

Comment: i been using the script however am noticing recently that the script isnt working it just stops completely or goes extrememly slow or fast??

Comment: While the game runs smoothly?  Some heavy processes are running in the background?